# UITextField is not updated immediatly after it's just loose the focus and during the closing of the keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, uitextfield

I have a strange problem, I have some `UITextField` in my form and I can move them instantly (when they have the focus or not), all moves are synch with the `drawrect` of the main view.

the problem is that **when one `UITextField` is focused**, when **i remove the focus that will also dismiss the keyboard**, then **all moves or updates** (like opacity for example) **are delayed for 200-300ms!** like waiting the closing of the keyboard. the `drawrect` still work, but the update on the `UITextfield` are not reflected.

It's look like that all update i made to the `UITextField` are postponed 200-300 ms later BUT the DRAWRECT of the main UI view is still firing every 16ms (so app is not frozen)

Any idea what is wrong ? what i can do to force the UI field to refresh ?

Comment: Hmm... Hard to tell what you are asking. Can you share some code?

Comment: thanks Rob, quite complicate to share some code as the framework is quite big :( but Is their any function that can force the visual update to be visible immediately ?

Comment: What does your `drawRect` method do exactly? Also, what triggers your `drawRect` method to be called? Are you calling `setNeedsDisplay`? If you register for `keyboardWillShowNotification` or `keyboardWillHideNotification` is there anything you can do there? It may be possible to animate some of your changes alongside the keyboard animations.

Comment: @rob drawRect draw to content of the main view, and all uitextfield are in some sub views. drawrect is triggered by setNeedsDisplay, so application is not frozen. regarding keyboardWillHideNotification, i receive the notification, but everything i do in this event to the uitextfield is not reflected immediately, I will see the update 200-300 ms later (look like I will see it when the keyboard will be effectively hidden)

Note: i didn't have this problem before to update to ios13

Comment: Sorry man, without seeing your code I don't think I can help you much more. If you can post it on github I'd be willing to take a look.